# Is the modification / removal of service by a private organization during the term of service illegal?

Tags: contract-law, common-law, advertisements

Suppose an organization have advertised to provide multiple services throughout the course of a year. Each service is sequential, one begins as the previous ends.

The organization has advertised that at the end of each service, you are allowed to choose the next service from a pool of services. Service X, Y and Z caught your attention and you decide to apply. Note that service X and Z is only available in the second half of the year.

Half way through the year, as your 5th service is coming to an end, this organization informs you that both service X and Z have been removed from the pool, and is no longer available.

Suppose your contract did not explicitly state that the organization reserves all rights to modify the service pool, would this be illegal?

If so, what are your legal options?

Answer (score 1):

As always, it will depend on the precise details of the case, and of *exactly* what the contract said.

You haven't specified a jurisdiction, but if this were in England and Wales, and you are a consumer (not a business), I *think* Trading Standards would regard it as an unfair term that they could vary what they offered like that without offering you the chance to end the contract.  (And an unfair term is void in a contract between a business and a consumer.)

If they had a notice "all services are subject to variation", they would be on stronger ground.

In practical terms, your best bet is to negotiate for an early end to the contract, and if that fails, to talk to your local equivalent of Trading Standards.

Answer (score -2):

Product or service, the company would have a right to modify what it offers. Unless you have it in writing or the company is underwritten, you really have no legal options as far as logic would go.

Comment: This is a site about the law - logic is not applicable